# spacing problem after \makebox

Tags: spacing, boxes

The following two lines give me different results with respect to spacing:

```
\noindent\makebox[\parindent]{?} Blabla

\noindent\makebox[\parindent]{?}Blabla
```

The second case is what I want: no space is added between the end of the box and the next letter. However, this piece of code is part of a customized command of mine (to give a simplified example: `\newcommand{\myBox}{\noindent\makebox[\parindent]{?}}`) and I cannot seem to avoid this extra space after using my customized command.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a full usage example demonstrating your issue.  For example, there is a syntax error in `\newcommand{myBox}{...}` as `myBox` is not a macro name.

Comment: Copy and past the two lines in a latex file, that should be it! (I corrected myBox into \myBox, thanks.)

Comment: The 2 lines of code are not the macro.  Your problem is with a macro.  So, please provide code beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{documemt}` in which you define your macro and use it in a way that shows the problem.

Comment: There must be something else: I have no problem with your simplified macro.

Comment: If `\myBox` is defined like that, then `\myBox Blabla` will be equivalent to the second construction at the top of your question.

Comment: Sorry guys, you are right. I have found the problem in the end: it was a missing '%' after the \makebox[]{} command. I was not aware of the importance of the % symbol...